# jQueryUI .dialog("close") not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using jQueryUI's dialog with the modal form option to open a popup form. When the user clicks a button, it submits their input to a database, and then should close the dialog. Everything is working EXCEPT the closing of the dialog. (The manual Close button works; it just doesn't automatically close after coming back from the PHP database script. Here's the script code. (I tried to bold the line that's not working; apparently you can't nest bold inside of code tags, but the line is surrounded with double asterisks to make it stand out. Those are not part of the actual code!)

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        var name = $( "#name" ),
            email = $( "#email" ),
            company = $( "#company" ),
            plate = $( "#plate"),
            allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( company ).add( plate ),
            tips = $( ".validateTips" );

        function updateTips( t ) {
            tips
                .text( t )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
            setTimeout(function() {
                tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
            }, 500 );
        }

        function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
            if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
                o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
                    min + " and " + max + "." );
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
            if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
                o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                updateTips( n );
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 390,
            width: 350,
            position: 'top',
            modal: true,
            zIndex: 3000,
            buttons: {
                "Submit your plate": function() {
                    var bValid = true;
                    allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

                    bValid = bValid && checkLength( plate, "plate code", 1, 7 );
                    bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
                    bValid = bValid && checkLength( company, "company", 1, 100);

                    bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ismi@instoremarketer.org" );


                    if ( bValid ) {

                            var nameStr = name.val();
                            var emailStr = email.val();
                            var companyStr = company.val();
                            var plateStr = plate.val();

                            var string = 'name='+ nameStr+'&email='+emailStr+'&company='+companyStr+'&plate='+plateStr;
                            //alert('string: '+string);


                            $.ajax({
                               type: "POST",
                               url: "submit_plate.php",
                               data: string,
                               dataType: 'json',
                               cache: false,
                               success: function(returnData){
                                                            alert(returnData.msg);
                                if(returnData.error === false) {
                                    **$( this ).dialog( "close" );**
                                }
                                else {
                                    alert("Error: "+returnData.msg);
                                }
                              }

                             });


                    }
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            }
        });

        $( "#submit-plate" )
            //.button()
            .click(function() {
                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
            });
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas?
**EDITED TO ADD PHP CODE**

```
<?php
include('../cfg/ez_sql.php');
include('../cfg/db_setup.php');

$err = false;
if (isset($_REQUEST['plate'])) {

    $raw = "INSERT INTO dot_plate_submissions (plate_code, plate_name, plate_company, plate_email) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')";
    $clean = sprintf($raw,
               mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['plate']),
               mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['name']),
               mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['company']),
               mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email']));

    //error_log("cleaned query: $clean");

   $db->query($clean);
}
else {
    $err = true;
}

if($err) {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = "There was an error submitting your plate";
}
else {
    $return['error'] = false;
    $return['msg'] = "made it to php";
}
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

So even if the error is false, the ajax call should still get back two pieces of data.

Comment: You assume that the success callback function is being executed. Can you add an alert before your .dialog, in the else statement, and after the $.ajax call? Then we can locate where the problem is.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're referring to. There is no .dialog in my success else statement. It's in the if statement. Do you mean add an alert there to make sure it's correct? I just tried that, and the alert did not occur. It did post the data to the database though, so apparently the if statement is not getting back what it expects. Is there any way to display the json that's being sent back? If I deliberately set the PHP to return error = true, the alert in the else statement does work.

Comment: You should have an alert to show you what the returnData is exactly. Place the alert before the if statement altogether. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Tried that; the alert doesn't happen at all. So even though it's posting to the database, success apparently isn't happening. Any ideas? I'm going to add the PHP code to the OP so you can see what's happening there - maybe it's not returning things correctly?

Comment: Try accessing your PHP script from the browser using a GET request. See if you get the appropriate return data.

Comment: I've tried that - changing $_REQUEST to $_GET in the PHP file, then going to http://mysite.com/mypage.php?name=myname&plate=myplate&email=myemail&company=mycompany. I get {"error":false,"msg":"made it to php"}

Comment: Actually, $_REQUEST encompasses $_GET and $_POST, so you don't have to switch between them. Hmmmmm. This is most strange. You could try setting error: and complete: callbacks too to see if they get called by using alerts. I am impressed. This should be working, I do believe.

Comment: According to the API, error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown). What is jqXHR? I know it's the XMLHTTPRequest, but do I need to pass something in to the error function for that param? If so, what?

Comment: Just set it. I'm fairly sure it's entered in the callback for you when thr error is thrown.

Comment: I tried doing this: error: function(xhr, textStatus) {alert('error:' + xhr.status);} but that didn't give the alert either. So it's not calling success OR error, apparently. I'm completely flummoxed.

Comment: OK, I just gave in and replaced our downloaded jquery files with the linked versions from googleapis. All of a sudden, it all works. (I'm going to get yelled at for not sticking with the corporate standard version, but oh, well...)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I got this solved months ago but forgot to come back here and post the solution. It had nothing to do with my code; it was just a version conflict between jqueryui and jquery. I was using an older version of jquery; once I updated my library to the version that jqueryui required (and which was actually noted very clearly on the demo page; my bad for not reading closely!) it all worked correctly.

Comment: -1: it doesn't matter what your particular problem really was. What does matter is 1) the TITLE and the description that the OP (in this case, you) gave to the problem and 2) which of the given answers is the best, according to that same title and description. And your answer is certainly not the best, sorry.

Answer (score 26):

Change your $.ajax call to include a context so $(this) is valid in the callback:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit_plate.php",
    data: string,
    dataType: 'json',
    context: $(this),
    cache: false,
    success: function(returnData){
        if(returnData.error === false) {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            } else {
                  alert("Error: "+returnData.msg);
            }
    }   
});
```

Comment: That was my first thought, that this (as in the dialog) was losing context inside the ajax, but adding the context: $(this) line doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @EmmyS: Try adding `var that = this;` before the `$ajax` call, then do `context: that`

Comment: Thanks, but if you read the comments to the OP, you'll see that it's not that it's losing context - it's that the success function doesn't seem to be getting called at all, or isn't receiving any data back even though the PHP file is sending it.

Comment: Adding the context fixed my problem, as well :)

Comment: this is brilliant answer , just i added context($this) to my ajax call  work fine ,thanks

Answer (score 12):

when you initialize your dialog do something like such:

```
var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({....});
```

Once you're ready to close your dialog, rather than using $(this) try:

```
$(dialog).dialog("close");
```

I've had to do this in the past in solutions I've wrote where I experienced the same issues

Comment: I had the exact same issue.  I use the ASP UpdatePanel for AJAX on my page and your solution worked for me.

Comment: Fixed the problem for me, also using ASP.NET Update Panel

Comment: Worked for me following an XSL transform. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in the "error" sub function rather than "success" write:

```
$("#diaolog-form-id").dialog("close");
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Anthony Shaw's solution.  It worked great for me and I'm using ASP.net AJAX, so it looks like the problem has nothing to do with PHP.

Here's some simple JavaScript that does the job:

```
var DialogOps = function () {        
    var _dialog;
    this.showDialog = function () {
        _dialog = $('#dialog').dialog({
          // dialog options here
        });
    }
    this.closeDialog = function () {
        $(_dialog).dialog('close');
    }
}
var dialogOps = new DialogOps();
```

Call `dialogOps.showDialog()` to open the dialog and `dialogOps.closeDialog()` to close it.

Comment: Nope, nothing to do with PHP. As it turned out, the issue was that I was using a newer version of jqueryui with an older version of jquery. Once I switched to a newer version of jquery it worked correctly.